# Socket program gets stuck on client

Tags: java, sockets, client, server

A client/server program where the client sends a text file to server. The server takes the file, reads it and counts number of numbers, characters, spaces, etc, and sends back to the client.

The program works great when either send the file to the server, or make the server send string to the client after counting, but not at the same time.

**Client**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
class TCPClient 
{
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
    {



System.out.println("I am client");


        Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 9881); 


        File file = new File("D:\\test.txt");
        byte[] bytearray = new byte[(int) file.length()];

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        BufferedOutputStream outToServer = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());


        bis.read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length);
        outToServer.write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length);
        outToServer.flush();


        System.out.println("From server: " + '\n');
        String x;

        while((x = inFromServer.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(x);
        }



        clientSocket.close();


    }
}
```

**Server**

```
class TCPServer 
{
    //***** Functions for counting *****
        public static int number(String x)
        {
            int numCount = 0;
            char temp;

            for( int i=0; i <x.length(); i++)
            {
                temp = x.charAt(i);
                if(Character.isDigit(temp))
                {
                    numCount++;
                }
            }
            return numCount;
        }

        public static int character(String x)
        {
            int charCount = 0;
            char temp;

            for( int i=0; i <x.length(); i++)
            {
                temp = x.charAt(i);
                if(Character.isLetter(temp))
                {
                    charCount++;
                }
            }
            return charCount;
        }

        public static int space(String x)
        {
            int spaceCount = 0;
            char temp;

            for (int i=0; i <x.length(); i++)
            {
                temp = x.charAt(i);
                if(temp==' ')
                {
                    spaceCount++;
                }
            }
            return spaceCount;
        }

        public static int special(String x)
        {
            int specialCount = 0;
            char temp;

            for (int i=0; i <x.length(); i++)
            {
                temp = x.charAt(i);
                if(temp=='!'||temp=='@'||temp=='#'||temp=='$'||temp=='%'||temp=='&'||temp==':'||temp=='^'||temp=='*')
                {
                    specialCount++;
                }   
            }
            return specialCount;
        }

        //***************************************

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("I am Server");

        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(9881);
        System.out.println("After Welcome");
        while(true) 
        {

            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("After Accept");

            PrintWriter outToClient = new PrintWriter(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());



            byte[] aByte = new byte [1];
            int bytesRead;


            InputStream is = connectionSocket.getInputStream();

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream ("D:\\server.txt");
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

            bytesRead = is.read(aByte, 0, aByte.length);

            while (bytesRead != -1)
            {
                baos.write(aByte);
                bytesRead = is.read(aByte);
            }

            bos.write(baos.toByteArray());
            bos.flush();


            BufferedReader br = null;

            try
            {
                String sCurrentLine;

                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\server.txt"));

                while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                    System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                }
            }

            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally 
            {
                try 
                {
                    if (br != null)br.close();
                } 

                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            /*******Functions********/

                int numCount = 0;
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileReader("D:\\server.txt"));
                while (sc.hasNextLine())
                {
                    String line;
                    line = sc.nextLine();
                                    numCount += number(line);
                }

                int charCount = 0;
                Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(new FileReader("D:\\server.txt"));
                while (sc2.hasNextLine())
                {
                    String line;
                    line = sc2.nextLine();
                    charCount += character(line);
                }

                int spaceCount = 0;
                Scanner sc3 = new Scanner(new FileReader("D:\\server.txt"));
                while(sc3.hasNextLine())
                {
                    String line;
                    line = sc3.nextLine();
                    spaceCount += space(line);

                }

                int specialCount = 0;
                Scanner sc4 = new Scanner(new FileReader("D:\\server.txt"));
                while(sc4.hasNextLine())
                {
                    String line;
                    line = sc4.nextLine();
                    specialCount += special(line);

                }

                int lineCount = 0;
                Scanner sc5 = new Scanner(new FileReader("D:\\server.txt"));
                while(sc5.hasNextLine())
                {
                    String line;
                    line = sc5.nextLine();
                    if(!"".equals(line.trim()))
                    {
                        lineCount++;
                    }
                }

                //System.out.println(numCount);
                //System.out.println(charCount);
                //System.out.println(spaceCount);
                //System.out.println(specialCount);
                //System.out.println(lineCount);
                String x="Numbers: " + numCount + "\nCharacters: " + charCount + "\nSpaces: " + spaceCount + "\nSpecials: " + specialCount + "\nLines: " + lineCount + '\n';
                //System.out.println(x);
                outToClient.println(x + '\n');
                outToClient.flush();
                outToClient.close();
                bos.close();





            /***********************/


            connectionSocket.close();
        }

    }
}
```

The output on the Client side would be

```
I am client
From server:
```

I apologies if my code is messy, this is my first time with Java. So I hope you guys can help me out keeping in mind I don't know much about Java.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try using "same" methods for reading and writing. Example BufferedReader / BufferedWriter instead of PrintWriter